# Constructor-Prototype cyclic reference JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I was working a blog on `constructor` property of a function object and came across this line:

> The prototype property of a function Object has the constructor property set to the function itself

Meaning, the following function object

```
function Student(name,age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

will have the following prototype

`{constructor : Student}`

```js
    function Student() {
    }

    console.log(Student.prototype);
    console.log(Student.prototype.constructor);
    console.log(Student.prototype.constructor.prototype);
    console.log(Student.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor);
    console.log(Student.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype);
```

which means the prototype has the `constructor` property which is set to the function itself that has the same prototype object. Does this have some reasons or it was just a language feature. I couldn't find any reason for having circular reference here.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question. It makes sense to me though.  It is a user defined function so its prototype would be itself. The constructor would also be itself because of the context of being user defined in the global namespace.

Comment: "I couldn't find any reason for having circular reference here." --- how would you design it instead?

Comment: Yes it will not result in cyclic reference error unless you return `this` from `Student`.

Comment: @Madhu How will it result in an error? return value of constructor is actually ignored, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a80xo96q/)

Answer (score 0):

The `prototype.constructor` property is set to reference the constructor function so that objects instantiated by that constructor can check which constructor function was used to create them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is just a language feature. And a pretty useful one:

- the `.prototype` reference on the constructor is used to set up inheritance when creating a new instance with `new`
- the `.constructor` reference on the prototype can be used to access the "class" from the instance, e.g. to create a clone, to re-initialise the instance, to access the class name, or just for checking the value.